# Windows minimize when I drag them into the center of the screen

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, when I drag to either left corner or right corner of the screen, it takes up half of the screen space. But when I drag it back into the center, it minimizes back to its original size.

Is it possible to force the window to retain the shape?

Comment: This is the Aero Snap feature, which you can disable entirely, but I don't know if you can partially disable certain aspects of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to force the window to retain the shape.

No. When you drag the window back to the center of the display Windows restores the application to its last-configured "windowed mode" size. This behavior is not configurable.

However, because Windows always restores the application to its windowed size, the following workaround may be helpful:

With the application in windowed mode (i.e. neither maximized, snapped to half a display, nor minimized),  manually re-size the window to your desired size.

Now you can snap the window to a display edge or maximize it. When you drag it back to the center, it will return to the size you manually specified. Further,   this window size will be retained until you manually change it.